# How to customize GitHub overview page?

Tags: github, github-pages

can anyone explain how to customize the GitHub overview page?

I am trying to customize my GitHub overview page, but I can't do it. please help me.

Comment: Hi Abdullah and welcome to Stackoverflow!
Congrats for your first question! It can take a lot of courage to jump for the first time on SO!
I hope to see you ask a second question soon!
Also, check this guide on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
Best of luck around here!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a repository with you own Github username. Check more about this special repo here: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme.